# State why the function $f(z)=2z^2-3-ze^z+e^{-z}$ is entire

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Consider the complex function

$f(z)=2z^2-3-ze^z+e^{-z}$

First of all, I want to get down with the definition of entire function. Based on Wikipedia, in complex analysis, an entire function, also called an integral function, is a complex-valued function that is holomorphic over the whole complex plane.

A holomorphic function to me is the same as analytic function.

I don't see the difference, so I am just wondering if we can use Cauchy–Riemann equations to do this exercise.

Comment: Replace $z$ with $x+iy$ and split the function on the rhs collecting the coefficients of $i$ calling it $v(x,y)$ and the rest as $u(x,y)$. Now apply Cauchy-Riemann.

Comment: what's the difference between a holomorphism and analytic function?

Comment: Fancy terminology.

Comment: Often the term "holomorphic" is defined as "complex differentiable (on some open set)" while "analytic" is "locally devellopable in a power series" This turns out to be the same. But a priori this is not at all obvious.

Comment: For purposes of communication with others, in English, "entire functions" are no longer called "integral functions", although decades ago some people did advocate this, and for plausible reasons. Also, rather than "holomorphism", one would say "holomorphic function". This is a _local_ condition, just as "complex analytic" is a local condition. These are apart from requirements of holomorphic (=complex analytic-ness) on the _whole_ complex plane. Apart from these usage issues, @quid's answer is to-the-point, I think.

Answer (score 6):

An entire function is defined as a function holomorphic on all of the complex plane. This is correct. Further, yes this is equivalent to the function being analytic. In particular an entire function is given by a power series (and conversely a powerseries converging on all of the complex plane gives an entire function). Thus an entire function is (the same as)  a function given by a power series with infinite radius of convergence.

I am not sure what you mean by "Quotient Riemann equations." You could use the Cauchy-Riemmann equation to solve this problem. But this seems a tedious way.

Instead I assume the intended solution is to exploit facts about entire functions. Such as:

- The sum and product of two entire functions is entire.
- A  polynomial function is entire.
- The exponential function is entire.
- The inverse of a non-zero entire function is entire.

With these at hand the result follows quite readily. If you do not know those, try to show them first.